# Getting following Cmake error while building project using qt-creator

Tags: cmake, qt-creator

I was building the following project: https://github.com/apertus-open-source-cinema/opencine.

By use Qt 5.8 version and while building the project,  I am facing this strange issue:

> cannot find source file :/home/user/document/error in tried extension
>   .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M cmakeList.txt.
>       .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp .hxx .in .txx

Can anyone tell me why I am getting this error and how to fix it?

Thanks

Edit:
the whole ERROR message

```
/home/devendra/Documents/Error in " Util.asciify("build-opencine-master-Desktop_Qt_5_8_0_GCC_64bit-Default")": TypeError: Property 'asciify' of object Core::Internal::UtilsJsExtension(0x190d630) is not a function/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeLists.txt:13: error: Cannot find source file: /home/devendra/Documents/Error in Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp .hxx .in .txx
```

Comment: Please, show **exact** message, starting with words "CMake Error", so it will also contain the filename and the line where the error occured. In current form, it is impossible to even find, which code causes the error. Copy-paste the error message into the question post and format it as a code (`Ctrl+K` or `{}` button).

Comment: @tsyvarev actually i was trying to paste the whole image but it need more than 15 reputation to paste image . Thank for suggestion

Comment: No, the image isn't needed. It seems that you insert the message as a single line, whily it is actually multilie. Because of the the message is hard to understand (but it is possible to slightly understand it). It smells like you have some unusual characters in the path, corresponded to source or build directory. Which directories you use as a **source** and as a **build** ones?

Comment: @tsyvarev I have cloned this project into /home/devendra/Document/  as opencine-master ( source). There is a cmakelist.txt inside this  and i have opened that as new project in Qt 5.8 . I have done everything according  to this video and  instruction. https://wiki.apertus.org/index.php/OpenCine.Build_Instructions.

Comment: In Qt Creator in Projects mode (Projects tab on the left side), check the build directory of your project. That seems to contain funny content. To get rid of the funny content in the future, I suppose that pressing Reset in "Options > Build & Run > General > Default build directory" could help

Comment: The error message is very weird indeed. Try to run cmake without qt creator. There is the cmake-gui tool. It can prepare the project for you, it might work or you get another hint of what is failing. I suspect that you have whitespaces in soe directories, but I cannot say for sure.

Comment: Thanks all of you ,  the problem is solved .  It needed to specify build location,  thanks @E4z9